# Paypal direct recurring payment upgrade/cancel payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

How does `paypal` Direct recursive payment work (using paypal business acc)

1. If my client wants to `cancel` the `recursive payment`
2. If my client wants to `upgrade` his/her payment method

May i know the API calls i should make to Cancel a recursive payment and Upgrade a `recursive payment`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API call to Cancel, Suspend or Reactive a recurring profile.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/

You can use UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call to update the recurring profile.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/